# How to use clasp run with properties - the valid JSON format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api, clasp

Why does this clasp command no longer work for me?

`clasp run setProperty -p ['domain' 'mydomain.com']`

which runs this function

```
function setProperty(key,value) {
    let scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
    scriptProperties.setProperty(key,value)
};
```

```
PC:AppsScript-CLASP user$ clasp run setProperty -p ['domain' 'mydomain.com']
Input params not Valid JSON string. Please fix and try again
```

Is this an issue with my system or the packages?

I'm using

- Node v8.11.1
- Clasp v2.3.0
- MacOs BigSur v11.2.1

Comment: Unrelated to the JSON format, I was also using old versions of `node`. Updating to node lts helped. I also needed to update my .zshrc to work with `nvm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You forgot a comma and single quotes

As per the [example in the documentation](https://github.com/google/clasp#run) you must use single quotes outside the array and double quotes when using a string `clasp run 'setProperty' -p '["domain", "mydomain.com"]'`.

### Reference

- [Clasp run Prerequisites](https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/docs/run.md)

Comment: Thanks for the link, Jose! I wish the documentation included your simple example.